# Generate image dynamicllaly on client side

Tags: javascript, image

I have a application, which generate image dynamically (based on some data input) on server, and send url to user.
Image is much larger than text file, and it occupy too much disc space and network bandwidth.

Is it possible to generate image on client side, meanwhile the browser behaves the same as getting the image from server (still use `<img>` element)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could either embed the Image in the tag ( http://www.sweeting.org/mark/blog/2005/07/12/base64-encoded-images-embedded-in-html ) or use the `<canvas>`-Element.